# How to exports django models with foreign key to csv

Tags: python, django-models, foreign-keys, export-to-csv

I have this session model :

```
class session(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    responden = models.ForeignKey(responden, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    kognitifScore = models.IntegerField()
    sosioScore = models.IntegerField()
    fisikScore = models.IntegerField()
    totalScore = models.IntegerField()
    timeStart = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False)
    timeEnd = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False)
    duration = models.IntegerField()
    mark = models.ForeignKey(sessionMark, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    order = models.ForeignKey(sessionOrder, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Now i want to exports all this information to csv. And i try this :

```
def exportsCSV(request):
    sessions = session.objects.all()
    response = HttpResponse('text/csv')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=sessions.csv'
    writer = csv.writer(response)
    sess = sessions.values_list('id','kognitifScore','sosioScore','fisikScore','totalScore',
        'timeStart','timeEnd','duration','mark','order')
    for s in sess:
        print(s)
        writer.writerow(s)
    return response
```

which is doing good but the foreign models only returning their id.
how can i export all of them including the foreign model into a single row?

Answer (score 0):

So i just coming back and post my solution.

```
def exportsCSV(request):
    sessions = session.objects.all()
    respondens = responden.objects.all()
    marks = sessionMark.objects.all()
    orders = sessionOrder.objects.all()
    response = HttpResponse('')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=sessions.csv'
    writer = csv.writer(response,delimiter=';', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    id = sessions.values_list('id')
    sess = sessions.values_list()
    resp = respondens.values_list()
    mark = marks.values_list()
    order = orders.values_list()
    ready = []
    for s in sess:
        for r in resp:
            if (r[0] == s[1]):
                ready.append(s[0])
                ready.extend(list(r[1:]))
                ready.extend(list(s[2:9]))
                break
        for m in mark:
            if (m[0] == s[9]):
                ready.extend(list(m[1:]))
                break
        for ord in order:
            if (ord[0] == s[10]):
                ready.extend(list(ord[1:]))
                break
        writer.writerow(ready)
        ready = []
    return response
```

i just check each correspondent id, and add manually to an array. i think this approach is rather dirty and maybe there's more pythonic way to do this

Answer (score 0):

The simpler way to do this is with double underscore. So if you're writing out a list of users and you have a foreign key to a 'Status' table, you would go from:

```
users = infs.all().values_list('first_name', 'last_name', 'status')
```

to:

```
users = infs.all().values_list('first_name', 'last_name', 'status__description')
```

This worked for me.